# rails - installed rails but can't create app "cannot load such file -- active_support"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activesupport

I did `sudo apt-get install rails` and all seemed good.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information...
...
Setting up ruby-actionmailer-2.3 (2.3.14-2) ...
Setting up ruby-activeresource-2.3 (2.3.14-1) ...
Setting up ruby-rails-2.3 (2.3.14-2) ...
Setting up rails (2.3.14.1) ...
Setting up ruby1.8-dev (1.8.7.352-2ubuntu0.1) ...
```

But now when I try to do

rails new test

I get `cannot load such file -- active_support (LoadError)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would not recommend trying to load rails via aptitude, I would use [RubyGems](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3). Then just run `gem install rails`, and pass a specific version if needed.

Case in point, aptitude is trying to serve you up Rails 2.3, when Rails is currently on version 3.2. The command you ran, `rails new test` is the rails 3 version. In Rails 2 it would be `script/rails ...` something.

Specifically, you can try:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove rails  # remove the previous install attempt of 2.3  
$ gem install rails          # Install rails version 3+ (3.2 in this case).
```